# ObservableDictionary binding to combobox display value(MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, combobox

I have a problem with DataBinding. I have a WPF (MVVM) user control project. There are `Comboboxes` and `Labels`. Every `ComboBox` binds to an `ObservableDictionary<int,string>`. So my problem is that I just need to show the string part of dictionary on my `ComboBox`.

Also, the `Combobox ItemSource` changes depends on what is selected at previous `ComboBox`. And also that is MVVM pattern. There is a model and view model.

I tried setting `DisplayPath`etc. But I couldn't show just strings on combos. Always seeing `[0, sample]`, `[1,yes]`.

```
<ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="250,15,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Name="CBxerisim" SelectionChanged="CBxerisim_SelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding Derisimkodu}" />
<ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="250,45,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Name="CBxteklifDurum" SelectionChanged="CBxteklifDurum_SelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding Dteklifdurumu}"/>
<ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="250,75,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Name="CBxteklifSonuc" SelectionChanged="CBxteklifSonuc_SelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding Dteklifsonuc}"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the following properties (I'm assuming your `ObservableDictionary` inherits from  `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`):

```
SelectedValuePath="Key" DisplayMemberPath="Value"
```

I have tested using [this](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shimmy/2010/12/26/observabledictionarylttkey-tvaluegt-c/) implementation of `ObservableDictionary<TKey, TValue>`

In my View:

```
<ComboBox Width="35" SelectedValuePath="Key" DisplayMemberPath="Value" ItemsSource ="{Binding FirstDictionary}"/>
```

And my View Model:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private ObservableDictionary<int, string> _firstDictionary;

    public ViewModel()
    {
        _firstDictionary = new ObservableDictionary<int, string>()
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<int, string>(1, "A"),
                    new KeyValuePair<int, string>(2, "B"),
                    new KeyValuePair<int, string>(3, "C")
                };
    }

    public ObservableDictionary<int, string> FirstDictionary
    {
        get { return _firstDictionary; }
        set { _firstDictionary = value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="Value"></ComboBox>
```

You can use the SelectedValuePath-Attribute the same way with the property name as a simple string (it's not a regular Binding).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your type "ObservableDictionary" is an ordinary or inehriting from Dictionary you can bind the display and value from the combobox.

```
 comboBox.ItemsSource = dictionary; // your collection
 comboBox.SelectedValuePath = "Key"; // dictionary key
 comboBox.DisplayMemberPath = "Value"; // dictionary content
```

I would recommend using a simple `List<YourClass>` if the user isn't adding or removing items.